# JFrame check boxes interaction

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

I would like to ask you something about JFrame and I think that I am wrong somewhere because this is happening:

I have placed on my Window Form 2 checkboxes (DocumentCheckBox and FilescheckBox). Here is the code

```
final JCheckBox DocumentCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Document");
ProduceDataDropDown.disable();
DocumentCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        FilecheckBox.setSelected(false);
    }
});     
DocumentCheckBox.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
DocumentCheckBox.setBounds(184, 131, 123, 23);
contentPane.add(DocumentCheckBox);


final JCheckBox FilecheckBox = new JCheckBox("File");
FilecheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        DocumentCheckBox.setSelected(false);
    }
});
FilecheckBox.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
FilecheckBox.setBounds(184, 157, 123, 23);
contentPane.add(FilecheckBox);
```

What is the wrong here?  ..... the second one works but the first one cannot find the FilecheckBox - it says that the class doesn't exist.

In short because the FilecheckBox is below than the DocumentCheckBox, it cannot be recognised.

On the other hand DocumentCheckBox is recognised at the second part because it is above and eclipse can recognise it.

Is there any way to fix this ??? What I want is when I tick one checkbox other one is deselected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, Try to follow the Java conventions: variable and attribute names should start by lowcase, I needed a while to realize that FilecheckBox wasn't a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You construct the FileCheckBox after you make the call FilecheckBox.setSelected(false);
Construct it at the same time as the DocumentCheckBox and then it will be able to find it.

```
final JCheckBox DocumentCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Document");
final JCheckBox FilecheckBox = new JCheckBox("File");
ProduceDataDropDown.disable();
DocumentCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        FilecheckBox.setSelected(false);
    }
});     
DocumentCheckBox.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
DocumentCheckBox.setBounds(184, 131, 123, 23);
contentPane.add(DocumentCheckBox);


FilecheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        DocumentCheckBox.setSelected(false);
    }
});
FilecheckBox.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
FilecheckBox.setBounds(184, 157, 123, 23);
contentPane.add(FilecheckBox);
```

Comment: Cheers man .... didn't know that we can change it that way. I was expecting eclipse to do it automatically like VS